# What Jewish print periodicals do you read?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

If you read (even if not regularly) any Jewish newspapers or magazines, please post them as answers, one publication per answer. If someone else has already posted a publication that you also read, vote that answer up; please don't up-vote an answer otherwise. Feel free to include comments in the answer text or in comments on the answers about the virtues of this publication and its fit with the crowd here.

The list generated here will be used for determining what publications to target for either [advertising](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319) and/or [reaching out to journalists](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320).

Comment: Why isn't this in the main site? Is this not related to Jewish Life?

Comment: For one thing, it's a poll question without a correct answer. (I realize that there are plenty of examples of such on [main], but I'm not sure it's a good idea.) For another thing, my motive in posting it is entirely meta.

Comment: Is the criteria for a question asked in the main section that it has a right answer? I understood the right answer to be the best answer as chosen by the community/asker.

Comment: It should be possible for there to be *an* answer that satisfies the question. See [this section](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) of the boilerplate [FAQ] and [this meta-question](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43/appropriateness-of-survey-questions). Note that this is one area of scope definition about which there's some disagreement within the community, but my personal preference is toward leaving polls out, so I personally avoid posting them on [main].

Comment: Yesterday when I visited the site I was greeted by several highly inappropriate posts. Amongst them was one on "sugar daddies" (now happily removed completely), "How can I determine if someone is Shomer Negiah?" and "Is Baal the Same with God?" now closed but still viewable. We propose to advertise the site in Jewish newspapers or magazines. What would be the effect on a first-time visitor of seeing posts similar to the above? Would it be more appropriate to advertise after a system was introduced to act more quickly on difficult posts?

Comment: Thank you for converting the above message from an answer to a comment. Please note the offending question has turned up again in meta in a slightly modified form.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok there isn't much that CAN be done (short of asking a non-Jew (in a permissible way, of course) to police this site over Shabbos (how could he know what is appropriate or not is a different question)

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, 1) The Baal question could possibly be salvaged into a worthwhile queston, so I left it closed but not deleted. The Negiah question was appropriate. 2) The issue you bring up is an issue before we advertise as well. We're very much open to the public, and we get hundreds of people coming in through search every day. 3) Let's discuss the actual issue here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/576/what-if-anything-should-we-do-about-offensive-posts-that-show-up-on-shabbat-yo

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - Why did you find the Shomer Negiah question to be offensive? I happen to know that the asker meant the question in good faith (she's sitting across the table from me right now) and genuinely wants an answer. I assume you were one of the people who voted to close?

Answer (score 2):

I enjoy reading [Jewish Action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Action), the [OU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_Union)'s magazine. I find that every issue has multiple articles that I find very interesting.

In terms of relevance to Judaism.SE: JA devotes a great deal of space to understanding how Jews live in contemporary times. It has, in the past, had a department and occasionally an entire issue devoted to technology.

http://www.ou.org/jewish_action/info/advertise_in_jewish_action

- Quarterly glossy magazine
- Color ads
- "Mail readership" - 50K (international)

Sample ad rates:

- 1/6 page - $950
- 1/4 page - $1300
- 1/2 page - $2000
- Full page - $3000

Answer (score 2):

[Mishpacha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishpacha) magazine

http://www.mishpacha.com

- Weekly glossy magazine
- Color ads
- Total readership: 250K (international)

Sample ad rates:

- 1/8 page - $575
- 1/4 page - $1150
- 1/2 page - $2250
- Full page - $4500

Answer (score 1):

[Zman Magazine](http://www.zmanmagazine.com/)

Stock disclaimer: I do not habitually read or subscribe to any print publications, but here's one I read from time to time, when I see someone has it:

Comment: I'm actually not such a fan of this publication, as I find it poorly written and prone to errors. However, I do see it quite a lot in peoples' homes.

Answer (score 1):

The Organized Kashrus Laboratory's (the O-K) [Kosher Spirit Magazine](http://www.kosherspirit.com/about.asp)

Stock disclaimer: I do not habitually read or subscribe to any print publications, but here's one I read from time to time, when I see someone has it:

Answer (score 0):

When I lived in Baltimore, I read the [Where What When](http://wherewhatwhen.com/), which is mailed free to many Jewish families all over Baltimore and greater Washington.

http://wherewhatwhen.com/advertising.asp

- Weekly newsprint magazine with glossy ad sections
- Color or B/W ads
- Readership: 40K (Mid-Atlantic US)

Sample ad rates:

- 1/4 page color - $130
- 1/2 page color - $200
- Full page color - $299

Answer (score 0):

[The Jewish Chronicle](http://thejewishchronicle.net/), Pittsburgh's weekly newspaper.  (I don't expect this to be popular, but you asked.)

Comment: I sure did. If you want to try [contacting reporters there](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/320/contact-reporters-to-promote-this-site), that'd be great. If we could get written up in even one local Jewish weekly, it could help us grow the community.

Answer (score 0):

[*American Jewish Spirit*](http://www.ajspirit.com/), a/k/a *[City] Jewish Spirit*, is a quarterly(?) glossy with editions for various cities, each with some common and some local content, and some common and some local ads. I sometimes read my local edition.

http://www.ajspirit.com/advertising.html

- Quarterly glossy magazine
- Readership: 35K (multiple US regions)
- Color ads

Sample ad rates:

- 1/8 page - $275
- 1/4 page - $495
- 1/2 page - $950
- Full page - $1800

Answer (score 0):

[The Five Towns Jewish Times](http://www.5tjt.com/)

Long Island Jewish weekly newspaper. Distributed in The Five Towns,  Queens, and Brooklyn areas.

Answer (score 0):

[The Jewish Press](http://www.jewishpress.com/)

Stock disclaimer: I do not habitually read or subscribe to any print publications, but here's one I read from time to time, when I see someone has it:

Comment: Not to be confused with the other Jewish Press - http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1003/1059

Answer (score 0):

[OC Jewish Life](http://www.ocjewishlife.com/site/)

Comment: Could you please split this into two answers so people can upvote either publication as requested in the question?

Comment: They share alot of content and ads, but done.

Answer (score 0):

Los Angeles [Jewish Journal](http://www.jewishjournal.com/)

Comment: Whats with the downvote? If you don't read it then don't upvote, if you think we shouldn't advertise there, comment with a reason. +1 to even the score.

Comment: @HodofHod a magazine which says that "the destruction of the Beis Hamikdash was the best thing that happened to the Jews"??!!

Comment: @ShmuelBrin what, where?

Comment: @HodofHod this was a front-page article of the Jewish Journal one Tisha Be'Av.

Answer (score 0):

[*The Yeshiva University Commentator*](http://www.yucommentator.org/advertise/)

Answer (score 0):

Omaha's [The Jewish Press](http://www.jewishomaha.org/jewish-press/)

Mission statement:
Founded in 1920, the award-winning Jewish Press is the Omaha Jewish community’s definitive source for local, national and international Jewish news. The Jewish Press is an agency of the Jewish Federation of Omaha and publishes weekly every Friday.

Comment: Not to be confused with the other Jewish Press - http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/617/1059