# Block new or very low reputation users from posting on Shabbat

Tags: feature-request, reputation, new-users, sabbath-observance

It seems quite common here that Spam, Rude, or otherwise inappropriate posts tend to accumulate over Shabbat when most of the posters are not present. This portrays a bad image of the site to others, especially Gentiles who are not observing Shabbat.

New users, or very low reputation users, should not be allowed to post on Shabbat. I propose that we do something very similar to what is currently done with Protected Posts on Stack Exchange - require the poster to earn 10 rep *on this site*.

The following message (or similar) could be displayed:

> Posting on Shabbat is restricted due to spam and rude posts that have had to be removed after Shabbat. To post now, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count). This restriction will be lifted when Shabbat ends. Shabbat will be over at [time].

As to what hours would "count" as Shabbat for this site, I would propose one of the following:

- It is Shabbat on Mi Yodeya when it is Shabbat in either New York or Israel.
- It is Shabbat on Mi Yodeya when it is Shabbat anywhere in the USA, or in Israel.
- It is Shabbat on Mi Yodeya when the user's geolocation data indicates that it is Shabbat at their location.

This feature would not actually *prevent* anyone from posting, it would only help ensure that new users, whose motives are not yet clear (e.g. is the wannabe Shabbat-posting user a drive-by spammer, a troll, or a genuinely interested Gentile?), make their first posts during times when moderation is more likely to be quick and effective.

Comment: this was already suggested here https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/576/759

Comment: Do we have statistics about how common this problem actually is?