# Where did you find Judaism.SE?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, community

Similar to [What Jewish print periodicals do you read?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/what-jewish-print-periodicals-do-you-read).

---

How did you find out about Judaism.SE (friends/google/ads)?

- Please write one source per answer. (If ads, please write the ad's location).
- Upvotes signify that you also came through that source.
- Please do not upvote for other reasons.

Comment: I don't think we have ads yet, but it could be useful for the future.

Comment: If you upvote, it'd be nice if you also leave a comment on that answer describing any particulars.

Comment: If anyone first came via HNQ please post an answer saying so!

Answer (score 11):

I found Judaism.SE through Google.

Comment: Follow-up question to all who upvote this: What were you searching for? (Please answer in comments.)

Comment: I don't remember. I originally found it in its M.Y days, though I never had the time to answer/comment.

Comment: I don't remember. I found the site while searching for something, but I didn't register for a while. Then, according to my activity, I registered to answer this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7746/what-practices-are-affected-by-a-belief-in-demons . I would not have guessed this. I was probably doing some kind of search that lead me to this question, and decided to offer an answer.

Comment: @Menachem no one welcomed you :(

Comment: @ShmuelBrill only two days late: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7724/talis-gadol-for-unmarried-individuals/7824#7824

Comment: I searched the name "Rabbi Yaakov Hilel" and then the words came up "rabbi yaakov hilel tzitis out" and it linked me to here.

Comment: I was searching for info about the custom not to eat in a shivah house and found this site. Very glad I did!

Comment: I was searching for details regarding Heicha Kedusha.  Pretty obscure custom, this was one of the only websites that even came up with useful details.  Since then (November) I have learned quite a lot from this site!!

Comment: It came up in Google results just about every time I googled something about Judaism.

Answer (score 5):

I was a member of another Stack Exchange network site, and came upon this site through the network.

Comment: Now that this is generalized, comments from upvoters saying which SE site they came through and by which network mechanism they found Judaism.SE would be appreciated.

Comment: @IsaacMoses. That would be interesting, but less useful than say, the Google search terms.

Comment: Regarding which site, I guess I agree. Regarding which mechanism (e.g. browsing the list on StackExchange.com, sidebar ads, or the long list of links at the bottom of each page), I think there could be some real use for people who design such mechanisms.

Comment: I don't exactly remember, but probably through the network list.

Answer (score 3):

Isaac had posted a notice (back in m.y days) on an online forum.

Comment: Specifically, LinkedIn.

Comment: +1, I found a proposal about Judaism topic in Area51, and there Isaac Moses commented that there is already m.y site. I joined m.y and later migrated to J.SE2 with others.

Comment: I had seen the notice on a blog, but don't remember which one -- Hirhurim, maybe?

Comment: @Dave, [most likely](http://torahmusings.com/2010/03/announcements-147-miyodeya/), or it could have been [The Rebbetzin's Husband](http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2010/03/shh-rabbis-coming.html).

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think I actually saw it in both places.

Answer (score 2):

I joined mi.yodeya before it became judaism.stackexchange.com. I was told about m.y by Isaac Moses, [its founder](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/644), personally (that is, by offline communication or by personal e-mail (not on a listserv or the like)).

Comment: Why'd you switch from generic "personal communication" to specifically from me?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I thought it'd be interesting to count separately those lured in by you and those lured in by other users; also, to count separately those lured in to m.y and those lured in to J.SE (to forestall the other question, why I changed from generic to specifying m.y).

Comment: @IsaacMoses but by all means feel free to re-generalize.

Comment: I miss my former opportunities to exchange information with M.Y. founder @IsaacMoses by word of mouth.

Comment: Big fan of @IsaacMoses projects in general and was very excited to hear about this one.

Answer (score 2):

I was told about Mi Yodeya by a friend.

He quoted research that he did in a *chabura* in yeshiva.

Comment: When I found this question, I couldn't believe that no one else was told about it by a friend. Either I'm the first, or no one's ever seen this question.

Comment: B"H many more people have used MY than have looked at Meta and certainly than have seen this question. What about [this answer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1853/2), though?

Comment: @IsaacMoses My friend could very well believe that I had never heard of MY.

Comment: @IsaacMoses BTW, I found this question looking for your Shabbaton question -- scanned all [meta-tag:site-promotion] questions.

Answer (score 1):

I found out about the proposal (then in [commitment phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435?phase=commitment)) via [Joel Spolsky's blog](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/12/09.html).

Comment: I was not previously a StackExchange user, though I had heard of the site and occasionally used it (via Google) for debugging code.  I had not previously realized that the network covered non-technical topics too.

Comment: LOL, Judaism is non-technical?    ;-)

Comment: It's a different *kind* of technical. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Founded mi.yodeya, the site's SE 1.0 [predecessor](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from), and wrote the [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning-migration-of-mi-yodeya-com) to create a SE 2.0 home for Judaism in general and mi.yodeya's community and content in particular.

Comment: No one better upvote this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was told about the judaism.SE proposal on area51 by a friend.

Comment: Extra Details: Led by @IsaacMoses' comment on area51 promoting mi.yodeya, I registered there under the name "yaavetz", which you still might find in some of the comments to old questions/answers. My account on mi.yodeya was then merged with my existing SE account when we started beta here.

Answer (score 0):

found this site through a link in either a blogpost or comment on a blog post on [Mekubal's site](http://mekubal.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I was told about mi.yodeya (version 1) by a friend who couldn't believe that I had never heard of it.

Source: [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1883459#1883459)

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how I encountered the site.

Comment: Whoa. If an upvote means "me too," does a downvote mean "I did the opposite"? I think this is a legitimate (though not very useful) response, and the voting scheme requested in the question should be honored.

Comment: If so, then I could down-vote all the other answers.

Comment: I'm upvoting to cancel out the downvote.